# Open .heic bitmap file in SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, skiasharp

Using C# and SkiaSharp I want to open a .heic bitmap image. My goal is to convert the .heic file to a .png or .jpg.

I have tried the following code:

```
SKBitmap bmp = SKBitmap.Decode(filePath);
```

When the filePath is to a .heic file it returns null. When the filePath is to e.g. a .jpg or .png it works fine. But I need to open .heic files.

Alternatively, are there other ways in C# to convert .heic files to .png or .jpg?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in current version (v1.68.1.1) of SkiaSharp .heic really just isn't supported.

The alternative way is to use [ImageMagick.Net](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) which is available as a Nuget package.

It is used as follows:

```
using (MagickImage bmp = new MagickImage(inpath))
{
   bmp.Write(outpath, MagickFormat.Jpg);
}
```

If anyone knows how to get SkiaSharp to support .heic, please say so.